# How to make time dropdown box default to current time?

Tags: php, select, time, timezone

I have a PHP script for a select dropdown box to display times in 15 minute intervals; however, I'd like to have it default to the closest current time (rounding up or down based on 15 minute interval).  Any ideas?

```
date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['TIME_ZONE'])

<label id="time_label" for="time" class="label">Time:</label>

<select id="time" name="time">

    <option value="">Select</option>

    <?

       $start = strtotime('12:00am');
       $end = strtotime('11:59pm');
       for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 900){
           echo '<option>' . date('g:i a', $i);
       }
    ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Just to be clear when the current time is 11:53-11:59pm the dropdown should select `12:00am`, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a convenient way to get the current time rounded up or down:

```
$time = time();
$rounded_time = $time % 900 > 450 ? $time += (900 - $time % 900):  $time -= $time % 900;

$start = strtotime('12:00am');
$end = strtotime('11:59pm');
for( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 900) 
{
    $selected = ( $rounded_time == $i) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option' . $selected . '>' . date('g:i a', $i) . '</option>';
}
```

You can use the following demo to test, just add either 450 or 900 to the `$time` variable.

**Edit:** As per the comments below, there is one condition that will fail because the rounded up time results in a rollover to the next day. To fix it, modify the `$selected` line to:

```
$selected = ( ($rounded_time - $i) % (86400) == 0) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
```

This ignores the date portion and just checks the time. I've updated the demo below to reflect this change.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/f086KR)

Comment: @YzmirRamirez Whoops! Had an extra parenthesis in the copy / paste. Fixed, should work fine now, thanks!

Comment: Just tried with `$time = strToTime('11:55pm');` and nothing was selected.  Was that intended?

Comment: It looks like it works because 12:00am is the first option in the list.  However in the original case there was a `<option value="">Select</option>` as the first element in the dropdown.  Here's the test with the `<option>` tags escaped:  http://codepad.viper-7.com/Is1Hmb

Comment: I see the problem - It only happens for a time between `11:48 pm` and `11:59 pm`, as they get rounded up to `12:00 am` correctly, however they roll over to the next day, causing the match to fail. Modifying the `$selected` criteria to ignore the day fixes this (I'll update my answer with the fix)

Comment: @YzmirRamirez - I've updated my answer which now correctly selects a date in that time range.

Comment: It works now!  Here's the Test case with 11:55pm selected - http://codepad.viper-7.com/dh9dOF

Answer (score 3):

```
<label id="time_label" for="time" class="label">Time:</label>

<select id="time" name="time">

<option value="">Select</option>

<?php

$start = strtotime('12:00am');
$end = strtotime('11:59pm');
$now = strtotime('now');
$nowPart = $now % 900;
 if ( $nowPart >= 450) {
    $nearestToNow =  $now - $nowPart + 900;
    if ($nearestToNow > $end) { // bounds check
        $nearestToNow = $start;
    }
} else {
    $nearestToNow = $now - $nowPart;
}
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 900){
    $selected = '';
    if ($nearestToNow == $i) {
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo "\t<option" . $selected . '>' . date('g:i a', $i) . "\n";
}
?>

</select>
```

Here some debug code I left in:

```
<?php

echo '<p></p>DEBUG $now = '. date('Y-m-d g:ia', $now) . "<br />\n";
echo "DEBUG \$nowPart = $nowPart<br />\n";
echo 'DEBUG $nearestToNow = '. date('Y-m-d g:ia', $nearestToNow) . "<br />\n";
?>
```

Comment: Here the above code with a 11:55pm test case that works (selects 12:00am option, second option in the list) http://codepad.viper-7.com/X5Q6r5